# number of distinct smaller elements on left for each position in a array

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I stumbled upon the problem of finding the number of **distinct** elements to the left and less than the element for each position in array.

**Example**:

For the array `1 1 2 4 5 3 6` the the answer would be `0 0 1 2 3 2 5`

It's straight forward to solve the problem in O(n<sup>2</sup>), I wish to know if the problem could be solved in O(n*lg(n)).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can just insert the elements into a balanced (red-black, AVG, whatever) binary search tree, storing the total subtree node count in each node. Updates are O(log N), as you only update along the path to root, and checking the number of distinct elements is also O(log N), as it requires summing the nodecount of left subtrees on the path from the new element to root.

This is how a tree might look after inserting [0,1,2,3,5,6], the subtree nodecounts in parentheses.

```
    2(6)
   /  \
  1(2) 5(3)
 /    / \
0(1) 3(1)6(1)
```

While inserting 6 (assuming it's last), you add:

- 2 (node count of left subtree of 2)
- 1 (the node with 2, because you take the right path, so root is smaller)
- 1 (the left subtree of 5)
- 1 (the node with 5, same reason, no left subtree to add)

Total 5. The tree is a bit too small to see the savings from keeping the totals, but note that you don't need to visit the 0 node, it's accounted for in its parent - the 1 node.

Comment: This solution only speedups the lookup of already calculated nodecounts. But question how to calculate the counts faster than N^2 is still open.

Comment: @Vitamon Not sure if I understand. The update of the counts after inserting each node is O(log N) (only nodes on the path to root are updated), so the whole calculation is O(N*log N).